# How to do global search in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, search

What I mean as global search is searching for documents in specified collections, for example, searching for a name in both User and Organization collections and will return both user and organization documents that match the criteria.

Is it possible to simply copy the documents in User and Organization into another collection and do a search in it?

Comment: Why are you storing them in separate collections?  A collection can include documents of any type, it's not a TABLE.

Comment: There are instances that it's better to separate two types of documents into separate collections as explained in MongoDB embedding and referencing docs. In this case of having e.g. two collections, is it possible to combine their documents into one collection? You wouldn't want to have a single collection for everything just to do a global search e.g. users, organizations, products, orders, etc in one collection.

Comment: Mongo docs state "documents in the same collection do not need to have the same set of fields or structure". Specifically you WOULD want to have them both in the same collection in order to index them by a common field and to be able to search across them.  Copying them into another collection is pointless when they can happily coexist in a single collection.

Comment: I just gave an example for two different documents. What I'm just trying to ask is, if it's possible to combine documents from let's say two collections into one collection. Now let's say I have user, product, shop, organization, and other documents, do you want those in ONE BIG collection?

Comment: YES, this is NOT SQL!  I have collections with hundreds of different types in them because they are indexed and searched together.  I also have hundreds of collections for entities that are never indexed together but are actually the SAME type (separate collections in this case because they are capped collections).  'Type' and 'Collection' are very loosely coupled in MongoDB unlike SQL.

Comment: it is not possible to combine two documents from different collections in one query.  There are no joins.  Having said that, that is not a good reason to dump everything in one collection.  It all depends on your use case and requirements.  If your requirements are to search all users and organizations at the same time maybe they are "alike" enough documents that they should be in one collection, or maybe you should be doing two searches, one in each collection.

Comment: Then I wonder why MongoDB offer some multiple collection examples such as referencing http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/#data-modeling-publisher-and-books if you can just store all types of document in one collection. It also realize normalization and de-normalization. So for those who want to have these separate collections setup and wants to combine documents from these collections what would be the best method? Some suggests map-reduce such as this http://goo.gl/9rGrJs or if there's more simple than that.

Comment: The use case is a global search, example is an e-commerce website which has products, users, organizations and a user can do search for all of these entities. Look at NetSuite where one can search for any entity such contact, customer, quotes, etc in a single search box, the same with Facebook's search which can return people, places, and things like regular user, fan page or group, movie, game in one go.

Comment: If your even thinking of using MR for this then you would have a more effective plan by shooting yourself in the foot, it is the worst idea ever, for example it doesn't even paginate parge joins, it just resolves the whole thing at once, without any speed or optimisations. Those who have been able to use this in production are the same people who are doing tiny little joins that could be done better client side. As for the best method, I would actually search the collections separately and do some kool UI stuff to make the search really intuative. Netsuite (I am a user) does this by having a

Comment: Search index separate to their actual database, I think they use lucene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do a multi-collection search automatically. There's no reason however that you couldn't perform the same query on multiple collections and combine the results.

While you could duplicate the data into another collection for query purposes, if you need to be guaranteed that the source collection's values matches identically with the "index" collection, you'll need to implement your own multi-phase transaction ([example](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/)) as MongoDb doesn't have a multi-collection atomic commit. Or, you can accept the fact that the "index" table may be out of sync. Of course, it could be periodically updated through custom code. Further, it means your working set has increased as you're double storing data.  Also, if you then need to grab data from individual collections (to grab more of the source document), you've likely not gained anything and made things worse when compared to doing multiple queries in the first place.

You could store related documents in the same collection and take advantage of the built-in indexing offered. Of course, this comes with the caveat that if your documents are now typed, you may find it more challenging to build MongoDb indexes that are efficient. Every changing/new document must go through the indexing pipeline, which may introduce significant overhead.

If it's only a few collections, I'd just do multiple searches without understanding more deeply your requirements. If not, the second best would be to combine documents into a single collection. Last choice would be to copy the data.

Comment: Thanks! Pardon I'm quite new to MongoDB, how do I combine results from queries on multiple collections?

Comment: Ok then that means handling of the paging will be on application level as well instead of using skip.

Comment: Unless, you put them in one collection. mongoDb may not be a good fit for your application.